# Variable value still zero after assigned a value

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm making a simple game using Unity where the player needs to pick up coins as much as possible. When the player hits the coin, the coin will disappear and the score will be incremented, for example by 1, here's my script

```
#pragma strict

var coinEffect : Transform;
var coinValue = 2;


function OnTriggerEnter (info : Collider) {
    if (info.tag == "Player") {
        // Debug.Log("Ball is picked up");
        var effect = Instantiate(coinEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        GameMaster.currentScore += coinValue;
        Debug.Log(coinValue);

    };
}
```

The problem is the variable `coinValue` is printed 0 when I print it to the console.

Any idea Why?

UPDATE i don't know why but if i declare another varible for example `number` = 12 and printed it.. It's working. But maybe this is a really strange case with the variable name.. I Don't Know.. Maybe, just maybe there is a flaw in their program for this varible name

Comment: printed it where? in a function, or at the file level?

Comment: printed it to the console.. using Debug.Log

Comment: I mean, where was the `Log` function call placed?

Comment: at the botom of the if statement in the OnTriggerEnter function.. `Debug.Log(coinValue);`

Comment: Strange, maybe an other function is null-ing your `coinValue`, you will have to debug it then.

Comment: have you any other code that could change the value of `coinValue` ?

Comment: nope, as i said in my update, the problem only occurs if i'm using `coinValue` as varible name other than that, the varible name like `number` will work

Comment: @AltianoGerung so that mean that an other code is updating the value of coinValue

Comment: i don't know a lot of fancy stuff about debugging.. i'm still a beginer with this Unity.. maybe i'm gonna close this question it's just very strange case and that's not really matter considering the logic of the code is right i think

Comment: @Hacketo that could be the reason, but i'm not wrinting so much code/script meaning that it's easy just to look at it, and i don't see any function that i made that change the value to zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using unityscript (not javascipt) the variable defined out side of the functions is set within the `inspector` view of the unity. Changes in the code to the initial values of these variables don't affect to values that are set from the `inspector`.

Select the GameObject you have attached the script to and find the script in the `inspector` view. There you can see the variable.

[image]

Comment: OMG... that's it.. thank you.. (i feel really ashamed of my self..hahah)

Answer (score 2):

As UnityScript [wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript#No_Global_Variables) says:

> **No Global Variables** Every top-level variable in JavaScript is global. Additionally, any variable declaration not preceded by the var statement is automatically scoped to be global. This is not the case in UnityScript; there are not really any global variables in UnityScript per sé.

This could be a reason.

Ps.: If you would like to have a solution for your current problem: define another class, with a constant field.

Comment: in his code there is the `var` keyword, so it could not be related with what the wiki says about global variables I guess.

Comment: As I read it, that clause only refers to JavaScript. Also in JavaScript *strict mode*, that isn't even true anymore.

Comment: Yes, but, in the OP code there is nothing that could be a global variable in Javascript as he is using the `var` keyword. Is `global` mean `outside the inner scope` for Unityscript ?

Comment: I am not familiar with UnityScript, but in JavaScript terminology, those are globals, as they are not belonging to the scope of any function.